# htaccess folder redirect issue while placing on root

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two separate projects of angular on root.

```
- Test1
- Test2
```

I want to build htaccess such that

1. all links with http://www.example.com should go to "Test1" folder
2. all links with http://www.example.com/admin  should go to "Test2" folder

I have written htaccess like following on root, but it's not working :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^admin$ Test2/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^$ Test1/$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is working but the issue with css and js file For example,

if css file is in "Test1" folder like name styles.css and in "index.html" file (located in Test1 or Test2) I mentioned css path like this:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
Then it is showing an error in console

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't touch existing folders/files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# /admin/* to /Test2/*
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ /Test2$1 [L]

# /* to /Test1/*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Test1/$1 [L]
```